# Regex deleting everything between the first "," and "\n"

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to delete everything between the two characters "," and "\n"

so for example this line:

```
@[@"Abend",@"evening",@"eve",@"even",@"eventide",@"time],
```

should become:

```
@[@"Abend",
```

How is this possible?

Also im searching for a possibility to make this line:

```
@[@"Abend",@"evening",@"eve",@"even",@"eventide",@"time],
```

to this line:

```
@"evening",
```

that means that just the first word between "@"" and ",@" should survie

Comment: does it have to be regex? couldn't you just take a substring? /^([^,]*)/

Comment: working with notepad++ but i think its no proble to do it with a small java programm

Comment: please tag the language you are using. *` Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.`*

Comment: What's the question exactly? And what have you tried?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace `^(.*?,).*$` by `\1` ([demo](http://regexr.com?34jqe)).
2. Replace `^.*?,(.*?,).*$` by `\1` ([demo](http://regexr.com?34jqh)).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @user1882812 Yep sorry, use `\1` instead of `$1`.

Comment: hmm.. that deletes everything :)

Comment: @user1882812 It does work by me. Click the "Replace All" button.

Comment: +1 but instead of `^(.*?,)` to match up to the first comma, it is more efficient to use `^([^,]*,)` which utilizes a greedy expression that allows the match to be made in a single step, whereas the lazy version requires a backtrack step on each character in the target string.

Comment: @ridgerunner Interesting, I didn't know. I'll keep it in mind, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how i did it, might be helpful :)

**For first requirement:**

```
^(.*?,).*$
```

**For second requirement:**

```
^@.*?,{1}(.*?,).*$
```